# Laravel: Many-to-many loop and access another table's data

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, relational-database

My situation:
I have `CAMPAIGNS` and `BANNERS` between these is `MANY-TO-MANY` relationship.

Each campaign can have multiple banners and each banner can belong to multiple campaigns.
The pivot table stores those relationships.
Then I have one more table where I store banner statistics.
The banner stats is a has-many relationship to the campaign, so I can access everything calling the CAMPAIGNS model.

Now here is the problem:
In the view I'm looping through `$campaigns->banner_stats` which allows me to access all statistics of banners assigned to campaign, but what I don't know how to access is the banner data in this loop (they have some parameters like name, URL, size etc.).

I can do `$campaigns->banners` while in the `$campaigns->banner_stats` loop and then have an if condition to match the banner ID to grab those additional parameters, but I think this is not the correct approach.

**I have a feeling that my design/relations are poor.** Also problem with it is when a banner is detached from the campaign then I will no longer get banner parameters, though the data for it will still stay in the stats table. So one loop will return different number of results than the other.

*Any ideas how should I approach this and improve it so I can easily access everything in 1 loop?*

Thank you.

Comment: with out seeing the db structure, your query(ies) and the desired output, no idea how to answer this

Comment: Looks like what I needed was a nested relation with some filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set 'belongsTo' relation from Banner Statisctic to Banner, something like this:

```
class BannerStat extends Model
{
    public function banner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Banner');
    }
}
```

after that you could call the banner inside the loop like this:

```
foreach ( $campaigns->banner_stats as $key => $banner_statistic ) {
    $banner = $banner_statistic->banner;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, given the lack of table definitions and queries (and I don't think "pivot table" means what you think it means), but I think you might want to perform a join in order to combine data from different tables in a single result. That would leverage the power of relational databases, instead of looping through tables manually.